# Serialize node.js stream object (which is circular) to JSON work around

Tags: node.js

I need to serialize the stream object that is the callback from a net.createServer()

```
var server = net.createServer(function (stream) {

  var json = JSON.stringify(stream);
```

However, When I do this I get a Type Error because the stream object contains circular attributes.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Why do you want to serialize the stream. You can't just pass a stream around to something else.

Comment: The server is asynchronous, you need to handle the 'data' event. Check out the stream documentation in the node.js api.

Comment: The reason I want to put this in JSON format is so that I can store the data in Redis.

Answer (score 2):

@Jason is correct here.  You want to take the data from the stream, not the stream itself, and put it into Redis.  In order to do this, you must add event listeners to the stream for the `data` and `end` events. In the event handlers you will get a chunk of data with each callback that you can either write to redis in pieces or assemble them in memory and then write the whole thing when the `end` callback occurs. Here's [an example you can follow](http://elegantcode.com/2011/04/06/taking-baby-steps-with-node-js-pumping-data-between-streams/).